# Read pdf file with node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to read pdf file fro url as follows

```
const axios = require("axios");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const PdfReader = require('pdfreader').PdfReader;
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

axios.get("https://url-to-pdf.pdf").then(function(result) {
    new PdfReader().parseBuffer(result.data, function(err, item) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else if (item.text)
            console.log(item.text);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {

});
```

It shows

```
An error occurred while parsing the PDF: stream must have data
{
  parserError: 'An error occurred while parsing the PDF: stream must have data'
}
```

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to ask a `responseType` of `arraybuffer` but then you have to transform it into a `Buffer`.

```
try {
    var options = {
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      headers: { 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.8' },
      timeout: 2000,
      responseEncoding: 'utf8',
      maxRedirects: 5,
      httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }
    let response = await axios(options);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
    if (response.headers['content-type'].indexOf('pdf') != -1) {
      console.log("pdf");
      console.log(typeof response.data);
      var buff = new Buffer.alloc(0);
      buff = Buffer.concat([buff, response.data]);
      temp = await extract_pdf.readlines(buff).catch(function (o) { console.log(o); return; });
      console.log(temp);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
    }
    else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```